# Randomly picking 6 balls

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I am trying to solve the following problem in basic probablity theory :

We are randomly picking $ 6 $ balls numbered $1 - 50$ (out of $50$, without replacment). If $X=\textit{minimum number}$ and $Y=\textit{maximum number}$ find the function $f_{X,Y}(k,l)=P(X=k,Y=l)$.

My approach is the following:

First, suppose that $0<k<l<=50$ and $k<=l+5$. Then: $P(X=k,Y=l)=\frac{\textit{favourable}}{\textit{all}}=\frac{{l-k-1}\choose{4}}{50\choose 6}$.

Now, in my notes instead of the above expression I have :$\frac{6\cdot5 {{l-k-1}\choose{4}}}{50\choose 6} $ but this seems incorrect , mainly because if instead of $50$ balls we had,say, $7$ the latter formula is wrong.

I would appriciated telling me if I am correct or pointing out my mistake(s).

Comment: Your answer sounds like the correct one.  The $6\cdot 5$ might have been in an attempt to account for where in sequence the largest and smallest ball were selected, however as we were running our calculations without reference to order in which balls are drawn it is unnecessary.  Had we been using permutations (*falling factorials*) rather than combinations, it would have been present in our calculations.

Comment: ${l-k+1\choose 4}$ or ${l-(k+1)\choose 4}$?

Comment: @DougM on both expressions I mean the second one, with the parenthesis. I will edit my answer. Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn't $k\le l-5$?

Comment: You can get $\le$ and $\ge$ using `\le` and `\ge`. You can get the proper font for text inside math formatting like this: `\frac{\text{favourable}}{\text{all}}`.

Answer (score 0):

As has already been stated in the comments, you're right and the notes are wrong. Your numerator and denominator both count the number of selections without order, whereas the numerator in the notes counts the number of ways of drawing the six numbers e.g. with $k$ being drawn first and $l$ being drawn last.